# Mapping to a collection of objects using XSLT from Legacy web service

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to populate xml using XSLT from data received from an external legacy web service which provides machine generated values for hotel information. They provide hotels with the element names having underscore and a number as shown below
  for example HotelName_1, HotelName_2 etc.  How do I to map these field names with underscores to my  elements?

```
 <!-- Web Service Results.. part of a larger schema, machine generated...-->
    <Hotel_Info>
             <Hotel_1>
            <HotelName_1>La Quinta Inn</HotelName>
            <HotelAddressLine1Text_1>552 12th Street West</HotelAddressLine1Text>
            <HotelCityName>Dickinson_1</HotelCityName>
            <HotelStateCode_1>ND</HotelStateCode>
            <HotelZip5Code_1>58601</HotelZip5Code>
            <HotelZip4Code_1>099</HotelZip4Code>
             </Hotel_1>
             <Hotel_2>
            <HotelName_2></HotelName>
            <HotelAddressLine1Text_2>3803 13th Ave S</HotelAddressLine1Text>
            <HotelCityName_2>Fargo</HotelCityName>
            <HotelStateCode_2>ND</HotelStateCode>
            <HotelZip5Code_2>58103</HotelZip5Code>
            <HotelZip4Code_2>099</HotelZip4Code>
             </Hotel_2>
             ....
    </Hotel_Info>

  <!-- Map to this schema     -->
  <AvailableHotels>
     <Hotel>
    <HotelName>La Quinta Inn</HotelName>
    <HotelAddressLine1Text>552 12th Street West</HotelAddressLine1Text>
    <HotelCityName>Dickinson</HotelCityName>
    <HotelStateCode>ND</HotelStateCode>
    <HotelZip5Code>58601</HotelZip5Code>
    <HotelZip4Code>099</HotelZip4Code>
     </Hotel>
     <Hotel>
    <HotelName></HotelName>
    <HotelAddressLine1Text>3803 13th Ave S</HotelAddressLine1Text>
    <HotelCityName>Fargo</HotelCityName>
    <HotelStateCode>ND</HotelStateCode>
    <HotelZip5Code>58103</HotelZip5Code>
    <HotelZip4Code>099</HotelZip4Code>
     </Hotel>
   </AvailableHotels>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I to map these field names with underscores to my elements?

Here's one way you could look at it:

```
<xsl:template match="Hotel_Info">
    <AvailableHotels>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <Hotel>
                <HotelName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="*[starts-with(name(), HotelName)]"/>
                </HotelName>
                <!-- more here -->
            </Hotel>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </AvailableHotels>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, if your schema matches theirs, apart from the underscores (and the underscores are consistent - unlike shown in your example):

```
<xsl:template match="/Hotel_Info">
    <AvailableHotels>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <Hotel>
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <xsl:element name="{substring-before(name(), '_')}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Hotel>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </AvailableHotels>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you mate, very much appreciated